# Multiple brotli processes at the same time

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, brotli

I currently have to compress several thousand files (~40-80MB each)  with brotli and get them ready for an s3 bucket.
From what i've researched so far, brotli can't multithread the compression so, brotli.exe uses ~10% of the cpu. How can I iterate through the files in a folder and spawn multiple (brotli).exe files to work at the same time (8-10 processes should fill the cpu)?
windows/powershell/vbs, I can try any suggestions

At the moment, I'm running this batch

```
for /R %%f in (*.) do (
"brotli" -Z "--output=E:\output\brotli\%%~nf" "%%f"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:: set limit to #jobs

SET /a limit=8

:: establish a subdirectory in %temp%

SET "control=%temp%\brotlicontrol"
MD "%control%" 2>NUL

:: Dummy for testing

for %%f IN (fred anna george bill betty carl celia daphne john kelly ian zoe brian
            tracey susan colin jane selina valerie david stephen) DO (
rem for /R %%f in (*.) do (
 CALL :wait
 START /min "brotli %%~nf" q75403766_2 "%%f"
)

GOTO :EOF

:wait
SET /a running=0
FOR /f %%y IN ('DIR /a-d /b "%control%\*.flg" 2^>nul ^|FIND /c ".flg" ') DO SET /a running=%%y
IF %running% geq %limit% timeout /t 1 >nul&GOTO wait
GOTO :eof
```

Here's a main batch which `start`s a subsidiary batch

```
@echo off
setlocal
ECHO.>"%control%\%~n1.flg"
REM "brotli" -Z "--output=E:\output\brotli\%~n1" %1
:: Dummy - variable timeout 5-20 seconds
SET /a exectime=(%RANDOM% %% 16) + 5
timeout /t %exectime% >nul
del "%control%\%~n1.flg"
EXIT
```

I had `%%f` iterate through a list of names for testing. All you need to do is to remove that test code and use your original code which I `rem`med out to process your list of files.

The process calls the `:wait` routine, which counts the `.flg` files in the temporary directory, and sets `running` to that value.

If the number running is greater than or equal to (`geq`) the limit established in the initialisation, wait 1 second and try again, otherwise the `:wait` routine terminates and the subsidiary batch `q75403766_2` is `start`ed `/min` minimised and with the name `brotli nameoffile`. It's important that the first quoted parameter to `start` exists as it's used as the title of the `start`ed process. You could use `""` if you want (for no title) but you should not omit this title string.

The sub-process started (`q75403766_2`) first creates a `.flg` file with the name of the file being processed in the `control` directory, then runs the `brotli` job (`rem`med out again) - I added a few lines to create a variable timeout to simulate the `brotli` process-time - and deletes the `control` file and exits.

The carets before the redirectors in the `for` loops tell `cmd` that the redirection is to be applied to the command being executed, not the `for`. `2>nul` (+caret) says "redirect error messages (file not found) to nowhere (ie. discard them)".